# Best Bets Missing When Query Contains Multiple Keywords

Tags: 2010, search, query

Let's say I have a Keyword "Hello", and a Best Bet associated to it called "Hello There".
Let's say I have another Keyword "Goodbye", and a Best Bet associated to it called "Goodbye Son".

- If I search for "Hello", I get the "Hello There" Best Bet (expected).
- If I search for "Goodbye", I get the "Goodbye Son" Best Bet
  (expected).
- If I search for "Hello Goodbye", neither Best Bet shows up (**unexpected**).
- If I search for either keyword with anything else in the query, neither Best Bet shows up (**unexpected**).

This behaviour seems counter-intuitive; I'd expect to see two best bets when I search for "Hello Goodbye" or "Goodbye Hello". Is this the OoB behaviour as designed or a bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 the Best Bet behavior is very unsophisticated. You have to develop a crude set of possible synonyms. If you want significantly better handling for your Best Bets you should look at SharePoint 2013 Search.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been hitting the Best Bet limitations at every turn! Unfortunately, upgrading to SharePoint 2013 is not a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: I understand, though you can add a SharePoint 2013 Search Instance without upgrading your 2010 farm and get the benefit of 2013 Search while you plan your upgrade.